# Accidentally shorted trailer light, now 4-pin trailer doesn't work on 2016 Hyundai Santa Fe

Tags: electrical, trailer

### The Car

I have a 2016 Hyundai Santa Fe Sport with a tow package on it. 60,000 miles on the odometer. We recently bought a 5'x8' Carry-On trailer to move a couple motorcycles cross-country.

### Problem

I accidentally shorted a trailer light while it was powered on and upgrading a light bulb from incandescent to LED. Yes, stupid me for not pulling the power before working on it.

The trailer itself is fine (AFAIK). The root cause (for now) is that I am not getting any power to my 4-pin trailer connector, on the back of the car.

### Background

The 2016 Santa Fe has 2x manufacturer-installed connectors, under the rear-left quarter panel for a trailer harness to plug into. I pulled the under-side protective panel off to view and re-seat these connectors. I cannot find a "converter box" that some trailer harnesses include, or a separate in-line fuse that's dedicated to the trailer in that area.

On the 4-pin connector, I used a multi-meter to test continuity between ground and each of the 3x 12v pins (running lights, left signal, right signal).

I have already checked the 30A trailer fuse in the engine compartment's fuse box. The fuse looks fine visually, and a multi-meter reads 0.000 ohms resistance across the fuse contacts.

The 30A fuse looks similar to this.

[image]

**Question**: What else should I be looking for, between the 4-pin trailer connector, and the fuse box, to find out why I'm not getting power to the 4-pin trailer connector?

To be clear, the short was **my fault**, not a persistent problem. I'm *guessing* a fuse is blown somewhere, but I have no idea where it is, or what else could be the issue.

Comment: There may be more than one fuse protecting that circuit.

Comment: I agree @Moab. Any ideas where I might find that fuse?

Comment: Resistance is not a good test for the fuse, run a continuity test across it to make sure it works.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan Have a look here>>>>>https://fuse-box.info/

Comment: Get the schematic and trace the voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Just had a similar thing happen. There is an inline 15 amp fuse by the factory trailer lite controller under the left rear cargo area side panel. You have to remove everything out of the cargo area. three screws hold down the side panel then a bunch of body clips. You don't need to completely remove the panel. about 6 inches in front of the controller is the fuse holder fastened to the wire harness. [image: controller is epoxied plastic box to the rear. The opened empty fuse holder is the white connecter looking thing]